# Automatically `expand-abbrev` with `org-meta-return` and `org-insert-heading-respect-content`

Tags: org-mode, abbrev

I take notes with `org-mode` and `abbrev-mode`. Normally pressing <kbd>SPC</kbd> or <kbd>RET</kbd> leads to any abbreviations at point expanding before the edit is made.

This doesn't happen when I use <kbd>C-RET</kbd> (`org-insert-heading-respect-content`) or <kbd>M-RET</kbd> (`org-meta-return`). Is there a way to make this happen simpler than advising those functions?

Answer (score 0):

A solution with advice is:

```
(defun expand-abbrev-eat-args (&rest args)
  "Call `expand-abbrev', ignoring ARGS."
  (expand-abbrev))
(advice-add 'org-insert-heading :before #'expand-abbrev-eat-args)
(advice-add 'org-table-wrap-region :before #'expand-abbrev-eat-args)
(advice-add 'org-insert-item :before #'expand-abbrev-eat-args)
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer assuming it resolves your question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in your `init.el` should do the trick:

```
(advice-add 'org-meta-return :before #'expand-abbrev)
(advice-add 'org-meta-return :before #'org-insert-heading-respect-content)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this out and it misses some corner cases (not purely `M-RET`, such as a universal prefix argument or `C-RET`) that advising `'org-insert-heading` instead gets.